# Painting a pixel picture in the least moves possible

Tags: python, matrix, artificial-intelligence

So a task we previously handed in was to try and generate a picture in the least amount of moves possible given a file. For example, a file would contain a matrix of 1's and 0's where a 1 is to be colored in, and a 0 is to be left blank. We would receive this matrix into a function called solution, and would be given access to 3 functions we could use to paint the image:

```
paint('line', r1, c1, r2, c2)
```

- paint all pixels in a line starting at `[r1, c1]` and ending at `[r2,
  c2]`
- starting and ending points are included
- lines can only be vertical or horizontal

`paint('square', r1, c1, size)`

- paint all pixels in a block starting at `[r1, c1]` (upper left corner) and ending at `[r1 + size - 1, c1 + size - 1]` (lower right corner)

`paint('erase', r1, r1)`

- erase a pixel at `[r1, c1]`

The solution I came up with was this one:

```
def solution(imat, painter):
    nrows, ncols = imat.shape
    for r in range(nrows):
        line = False
        curr_col = 0
        for c in range(ncols):
            if imat[r, c] == 0:
                continue
            elif c == ncols - 1 and line == True and imat[r, c] == 1:
                painter.paint('line', r, curr_col, r, c)
            elif c == ncols - 1 and line == False and imat[r, c] == 1:
                painter.paint('square', r, c, 1)
            elif line == False and imat[r, c] == 1 and imat[r, c + 1] == 1:
                line = True
                curr_col = c
            elif line == True and imat[r, c] == 1 and imat[r, c + 1] == 1:
                continue
            elif line == True and imat[r, c] == 1 and imat[r, c + 1] == 0:
                painter.paint('line', r, curr_col, r, c)
                line = False
            else:
                painter.paint('square', r, c, 1)
```

In the above code, `painter` is what performs the task, and `imat` is the matrix we are receiving. I'm curious to see if anyone could maybe come up with a better solution and explain a better way to go about this.

Just in case anyone is interested, the solution i proposed generates the picture below in 30 moves, with the lowest amount in the class having been 20.

[An example of a matrix received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7JMj.png)

[The matrix colored in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAqN7.png)

Comment: How big is the matrix?, it seems like this problem may be solved with a search algorithm. Do you need an algorithm that perform the minimum possible number of moves?

Comment: Multiple images are given in, so the matrix varies in size. The one given is just an example we used to work with, hence the size is changing and is always determined with the imat.shape call. Basically given those 3 functions, we need to perform the least number of moves to paint every cell that is a 1 into the picture expected.

Comment: Since you can only paint vertical or horizontal lines, the solution will be either the result of run-length compressing the matrix in row or column order. For reasonably-sized matrices, it would be feasible to do it both ways and choose whichever is smaller.

Comment: While that is true, the ability to draw a square of varying sizes is also available, and helps greatly in limiting number of moves made. Another solution i designed made use of squares, by grouping together the largest amount of 1's in the picture at a time, and managed to bring the number of moves down to 20, but in another picture where no large amount of 1's where grouped together, it failed miserably.

Comment: can you possibly post the other solution, maybe you can combine the two to get better results?